# FLEX - Set conditional locale strings in ActionScript

Tags: apache-flex, locale

I'm trying to localize my Flex app, I have been able to setup the locale specifics and all the stuff inside MXML tags, that works pretty well, my question is, what about if I have for example:

```
if(loggin){
  loginBtn.label = "Logout";
}else{
  loginBtn.label = "Login";
}
```

How can I change with ActionScript those two strings to an other locale?

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [ResourceManager](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/resources/ResourceManager.html)

```
if(loggin){
  loginBtn.label = resourceManager.getString(MyResourceBundles.LABELS,'login')
}else{
  loginBtn.label = resourceManager.getString(MyResourceBundles.LABELS,'logout')
}
```

The downside of this approach is that bindings won't fire if the user changes language midway.

Therefore, for this specific example, I'd reccommend states:

```
<s:Button id="loginBtn" 
   label.loggedIn="{resourceManager.getString(MyResourceBundles.LABELS,'login')}" 
   label.loggedOut="{resourceManager.getString(MyResourceBundles.LABELS,'logout')}" />
```